# Estou com um problema no django-views, ele não está salvando meu formulario

Tags: django

Esse aqui é o meu views:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from meusite.forms import CandidatoForm
from meusite.models import Candidato


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html') #renderizando (interpretando e colocando na pagina html)

def cadastro(request):
    return render(request, 'cadastro.html')

def sobre(request):
    return render(request, 'sobre.html')

def cadastrados(request):
    cadastrados = Candidato.objects.all()
    contexto = {
        'cadastrados' : cadastrados,
    }
    return render(request, 'cadastrados.html', contexto)

def fazer_cadastro(request):
    #ENTRAR PELA PRIMEIRA VEZ NO SITE USA METODO REQUEST.GET
    #ENTRA PELO CLICK ENVIANDO O FORMULARIO USA O METODO REQUEST.POST)  
    candidatos = Candidato.objects.all()
    formulario = CandidatoForm(request.POST or None)
    msg = ''

    if formulario.is_valid():
        formulario.save()
        formulario = CandidatoForm() #depois de enviar, apaga
        msg = 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso'

    contexto = {
        'form' : formulario,
        'msg' : msg
    }

    #CONTEXTO: MANDA COISAS DO PYTHON PRO HTML (ACESSA FORMULARIO DO BACKEND PRO FRONTEND)
    return render(request, 'cadastro.html', contexto)
```

Aqui é o meu models

```py
class Candidato(models.Model):

    genero_feminino = 'f'
    genero_masculino = 'm'
    genero_outro = 'o'

    genero_opcoes = [
        (genero_feminino, 'Feminino'),
        (genero_masculino, 'Masculino'),
        (genero_outro, 'Outro'),
    ]

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=" ")
    idade = models.IntegerField()
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=genero_opcoes, default=" ")
    data_nascimento = models.DateField()
    nacionalidade = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=" ")
    ja_trabalha = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    pretencao_salarial = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=1000, default=0)
    perfil = models.TextField(default=" ")
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='', null=True)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.nome
```

Por algum motivo eu não estou conseguindo salvar quem preenche o formulário nem exibir mensagens como "O formulario foi preenchido com sucesso!"
Alguém pode me ajudar a solucionar esse erro?

Answer (score 0):

como está chamando o formulário no template `cadastro.html`?
Como passou uma mensagem pro contexto, precisa chamar ela no template `{{ msg }}`.
Pelos testes que fiz aqui poder ser que o formulário tenha dados inválidos, verifique os atributos do model: `data_nascimento` e o `foto`.

```
{{ msg }}
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" name="button">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Espero ter ajudado um pouco, nos atualize do seu progresso.
Esse site tem muito conteudo legal. 
Talvez seja mais interessante de usar o framework de mensagens do django.
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/09/06/django-tip-14-messages-framework.html

Comment: Muito obrigada pela sua ajuda, eu vou tirar esses campos e ver se salva.

Comment: Infelizmente ainda não funcionou, mesmo eu tirando esses campos do código :C

Comment: Você poderia colocar o erro que está retornando? Como vc está testando?

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Amanda,

Tudo bem?

Amanda, reescrevi um pouco o código, espero que ajude:

```
#forms.py
from .models import Candidato
from django import forms


class CandidatoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidato
        fields = '__all__'


#views.py
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Candidato
from .forms import CandidatoForm


class CadastroCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, generic.CreateView):

    form_class = CandidatoForm
    model = Candidato
    success_message = 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('suaurl')

    def candidatos(self):
        return Candidato.objects.all()

#seu template html

#para exibir a lista de candidatos obtida no metodo def candidatos(), basta fazer o seguinte:
{% for c in view.candidatos %}
    {{ c }}
{% endfor %}

#aqui será exibido a mensagem de sucesso que é passada para o template através do 
success_message na view
{% for m in messages %}
    {{ m }}
{% endfor %}

<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

Amanda, se possível, roda um manage.py makemigrations e manage.py migrate novamente, caso tenha algum erro na sua view, forms, ou model, será exibido durante o processo.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda, eu consegui fazer meu formulário funcionar! :D

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o meu problema da seguinte forma:

VIEWS:

```
def cadastro(request):
if request.method == "POST":
  form = CandidatoForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
        candidado = form.save()
        msg = "Cadastro realizado com sucesso"
        return({'msg':msg})
else:
    form = CandidatoForm()       
return render(request, 'cadastro.html', {'form':form})
```